# Why can't I load Flickr.com using jQuery .load method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, cross-domain

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="abc"></div>
<script>
    $('#abc').load('http://www.flickr.com/');
</script>
```

But in  , there's nothing.

Where is error?

Thank you!

Comment: You got no <html>, <head> or <body> tags...

Comment: @benhowdle89: Although the HTML is not correct, it would not stop the jQuery from working.

Comment: @benhowdle89: A *lot* of elements can be left out of the markup as of HTML5, which is the doctype he's given. (The elements are still there via *implication*.) The rules are complex: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags

Comment: Following on... I don't claim the above conforms to the rules -- there seems to be a space character after the implied `</head>`, for instance -- but figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Yep. This is HTML5 document. :)

Answer (score 4):

The `.load()` function uses AJAX. AJAX doesn't work cross-domain, this is why it isn't working.

You can however use JSONP to retrieve Flickr data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Luca Matteis.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load external sites (different domain) via jQuery, unless your using the JSON functions.

Comment: *"unless your using the JSON functions"* **JSONP**, not JSON (and "you're" rather than "your")

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Kyle Hudson and T.J. Crowder.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can't use the `load` function for pages outside your own domain. But you could use an iframe instead:

```
<iframe id="abc"></iframe>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $('#abc').attr('src', 'http://www.flickr.com');
</script>
```